# How can I convert an Excel date into a JS date object so that they would be in the same format for calculations?

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm importing data from Excel and some of that data are dates that I need to performa calculations on. I want to calculate the difference in weeks between the current date and the date that was imported from excel. However, they are in different formats.

Format that the Excel date is in:

[image]

JS Date format (JS dates are formatted like this MM/DD/YYYY I believe):

[image]

As you can see, they are written in a different format and I can only perform calculations using the JS Date with date objects. How can I convert the Excel date into a JS date object so that they would be in the same format for calculations?

It might be helpful to know that I want to calculate the # weeks between the date in Excel and the current date.

Also, I'd like to avoid using Moment.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Covert the excel date string into a JS date object.

```js
let excelDate = "\"10\\/31\\/19\"";
let jsDate = new Date(excelDate.replace(/\\/g, ''));

console.log(jsDate);
```